# what publish subscribe on XMPP can make offline message like MQTT qos=2?

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd, publish-subscribe, smack

XMPP Server was provide us to get history with Retrieve feature. But my question is can I get item or message just between since offline date to online date?

My scenario is as follow:
User2 has subscribe topic A but user2 disconnect for few second and reconnect. when user2 disconnect, user1 publish message to topic A.

And i cant get that message...

Please help.

Comment: can you share the code, how you have achieve that?

Comment: @gaurang what you mean? I done with it.

Comment: how you have achieve offline message? can you share it?

Comment: oh, like xmpp basic get publish subscribe offline message. Just call method "retrieve" message. one of  parameter from that method is sum last message you want take from server.
so my app will ask for 10 last message and I input into my database where my database will not duplicate the message because primary key column. 
I will give code on my answer form. @gaurang

Comment: Sorry my acccount has been blocked. So I cant answer in here. Go to my git link. https://bitbucket.org/snippets/mochammad_irsyad/9oGRRr

Comment: thank you for this snippets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server have to support [XEP-0013](http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0013.html) extension. Ejabbered supports it only in Business Edition, which is paid. Consider using [OpenFire](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/).

Comment: whether it pubsub ?